# RGB to HSV in numpy

Tags: numpy, opencv, rgb, hsv

I'm trying to implement RGB to HSV conversion from opencv in pure numpy using formula from [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor):

```
def rgb2hsv_opencv(img_rgb):
    img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
    return img_hsv

def rgb2hsv_np(img_rgb):
    assert img_rgb.dtype == np.float32
    
    height, width, c = img_rgb.shape
    r, g, b = img_rgb[:,:,0], img_rgb[:,:,1], img_rgb[:,:,2]  
    
    t = np.min(img_rgb, axis=-1)
    v = np.max(img_rgb, axis=-1)
    
    s = (v - t) / (v + 1e-6)
    s[v==0] = 0
    
    # v==r
    hr = 60 * (g - b) / (v - t + 1e-6)
    # v==g
    hg = 120 + 60 * (b - r) / (v - t + 1e-6)
    # v==b
    hb = 240 + 60 * (r - g) / (v - t + 1e-6)

    h = np.zeros((height, width), np.float32)
    
    h = h.flatten()
    hr = hr.flatten()
    hg = hg.flatten()
    hb = hb.flatten()
    
    h[(v==r).flatten()] = hr[(v==r).flatten()]
    h[(v==g).flatten()] = hg[(v==g).flatten()]
    h[(v==b).flatten()] = hb[(v==b).flatten()]
    
    h[h<0] += 360
    
    h = h.reshape((height, width))
    
    img_hsv = np.stack([h, s, v], axis=-1)
    
    return img_hsv


img_bgr = cv2.imread('00000.png')

img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

img_rgb = img_rgb / 255.0
img_rgb = img_rgb.astype(np.float32)

img_hsv1 = rgb2hsv_np(img_rgb)
img_hsv2 = rgb2hsv_opencv(img_rgb)

print('max diff:', np.max(np.fabs(img_hsv1 - img_hsv2)))
print('min diff:', np.min(np.fabs(img_hsv1 - img_hsv2)))
print('mean diff:', np.mean(np.fabs(img_hsv1 - img_hsv2)))
```

But I get big diff:

```
max diff: 240.0
min diff: 0.0
mean diff: 0.18085355
```

Do I missing something?

Also maybe it's possible to write numpy code more efficient, for example without `flatten`?

Also I have hard time finding original C++ code for `cvtColor` function, as I understand it should be actually function `cvCvtColor` from C code, but I can't find actual source code with formula.

Comment: Could you check and report to us which colour has the maximum diff? Maybe it is just a normalization problem (black and white: just V matter: the other values are irrelevant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the fact that the max difference is exactly 240, I'm pretty sure that what's happening is in the case when both or either of `v==r`, `v==g` are simultaneously true alongside `v==b`, which gets executed last.

If you change the order from:

```
h[(v==r).flatten()] = hr[(v==r).flatten()]
h[(v==g).flatten()] = hg[(v==g).flatten()]
h[(v==b).flatten()] = hb[(v==b).flatten()]
```

To:

```
h[(v==r).flatten()] = hr[(v==r).flatten()]
h[(v==b).flatten()] = hb[(v==b).flatten()]
h[(v==g).flatten()] = hg[(v==g).flatten()]
```

The max difference may start showing up as 120, because of that added 120 in that equation. So ideally, you would want to execute these three lines in the order b->g->r. The difference should be negligible then (still noticing a max difference of 0.01~, chalking it up to some round off somewhere).

```
h[(v==b).flatten()] = hb[(v==b).flatten()]
h[(v==g).flatten()] = hg[(v==g).flatten()]
h[(v==r).flatten()] = hr[(v==r).flatten()]
```

Comment: Yes, order BGR helps to reduce max abs diff to 0.013458252, but diff is still too high to neglect it.

Comment: Hmm, removing `img_rgb = img_rgb / 255.0` helps to reduce max abs diff to `6.1035156e-05`

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this slight deviation might be caused by the 1e-6s added to avoid div by zero errors. Maybe break the division process to something like: `s=v-t`, `s[v!=0] = s[v!=0] / v[v!=0]` and `s[v==0]=0`.