# HSV to RGB in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, rgb, hsv

Here is solved [RGB to HSV in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63691352/rgb-to-hsv-in-numpy/) conversion, and here is a formula from opencv documentation for RGB to HSV convertion:

[image]

But how to reverse this formula to get HSV to RGB conversion formula? How can we reverse `max(R,G,B)` and `min(R,G,B)` ?

Comment: this seems to be a useful resource
https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/hsv-to-rgb.html

Comment: Surely Google could have given you the formula faster than you generated this question?  Here's one source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#HSV_to_RGB